# android - submenu click isn't selecting the right item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a menu with a submenu. The parent item is "Options" and its children are "Call", "Navigate", and "Edit". Here is my activity code that handles the menu click. The problem is that the first submenu always gets selected by the event. With this code if i click on "Call"(the first child item) the onOptionsItemSelected() method registers the R.id.record_edit item being selected. I don't know why this is happening since the "Call" menu item has the id of "record_call". I've tried switching the submenu items around in the xml but the first submenu item is the only one that registers and it always registers as R.id.record_edit. Not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.record_edit:

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditRecordActivity.class);
        myApp.setRecord(record);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("new", false);
        b.putString("pageTitle", pageTitle);
        b.putString("meta_universalid", meta_universalid);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

xml menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item
        android:id="@+id/record_options"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="..."
        android:titleCondensed="Options"
        android:enabled="true">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/record_call"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="@string/record_call"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/record_navigate"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="@string/record_navigate"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/record_edit"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="@string/record_edit"/>           
        </menu>
   </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just checked with your menu to be sure. It is working fine with me. Check whether your overall format is like the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.record_call:
        Toast.makeText(this, "call", 1000).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.record_edit:
        Toast.makeText(this, "edit", 1000).show();

        return true;
    case R.id.record_navigate:
        Toast.makeText(this, "navigate", 1000).show();

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. i just created a blank App project and did this and worked like it should. I can't tell what's different about my main app code.

Comment: you better paste your whole oncreateoptionmenu and onoptionmenuitemseleced.. may be that can reveal the problem